# Temporary Files

Tags: node.js, express

First of all, apologies in advance for any lack of understanding/clarity in explaining. I'm pretty new at this all.

I'm building a website using node.js, and I used Express to get everything started. However, any time I make any changes to any .js or .ejs file, it stores a temporary .js~ or .ejs~ file that doesn't go away unless I manually rm it. It doesn't seem to be doing anything else, but even when I push to GitHub, it's still there. It's kind of annoying - I don't want to have to delete them all by hand.

Any suggestions?

Cheers!

Comment: What editor are you using?

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni I've tried both Sublime and Emacs, and both give me the same issue.

Comment: Regarding GitHub, you can add `*.js~` in your `.gitignore` file, this way those files won't be added to your repository.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using emacs too, to avoid creating backup files I've got this in my configuration

```
(setq make-backup-files nil)
```

If you have a vanilla installation of emacs you should put it in `init.el`, otherwise that depends on how you set it up.